# Run a bash script located in remote VM

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I have two VMs, Vm-A & Vm-B.

I have two scripts: one in VM-A & another in VM-B

VM-A has a bash script which gets CPU% every second & saves it to a variable `$cpu`.

VM-B has a bash script which does some actions according to CPU%

I want to execute the script on VM-B `(bash scriptb.sh arg1)` every second with `$cpu` from VM-A

How can I do this using ssh or php?

I tried searching a lot on google but could not get anything that I can understand.

Comment: so, what did you find, and what did you *not* understand

Comment: it´s hard to write something you understand if chances are our text are very similar to those you did not understand, since you leave us no clue what you *would* in fact understand.

Comment: @MarcusMüller all i found that executing script to vm b from vm a but the examples are with script of vmb located in vm a

Comment: again, not clear what you not understand there

Comment: in above post arg1 = $cpu value from vm-a

Comment: ScriptA Located in VMA, ScriptB Located in VMB. I want the variable generated from ScriptA to be used as a argument for running ScriptB in VMB.. I guess I am clear now :)

Comment: Is your question: "How do I pass data from one script to another. Where each script is running on different machines via `ssh`?"?

Comment: Have you considered using a pipe-line?

Comment: I dont know about pipline very new to bash

Comment: A pipeline is what you make with the `|` character. I would get it to work (using a pipeline) on one machine before trying to get it to work on two.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? If so then the help you need will differ.

Answer (score 0):

Write the scripts to use `stdin` and `stdout`.

Then on machine A do:

```
script-A | ssh machine-B script-B
```

Or on machine B do:

```
ssh machine-A script-A | script-B
```

To give temporary access to keys you can log-in to machine-A using `ssh -A`.
Ensure that you trust machine-A. If not then you can use a sand-boxed account on B, and a custom key that gives access to this sand-boxed account only. You can even configure `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` of this account, to run the script and only the script.